# Using df.to_sql(if_exists='append') with sqlalchemy to UPSERT in SQL Server table

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, orm, upsert

I'm trying to insert a dataframe into a SQL Server table using sqlalchemy. I've been using the `df.to_sql(if_exists='append')` method thinking its' behavior would be similar to an UPSERT but am realizing now that this is not the case.

What is happening is that 'append' can only add onto an existing table but cannot update individual rows if there are already present in the table. I'm really trying to avoid looping in the dataframe but looks like it's the only thing that will work here unless perhaps I've misunderstood something in the ORM.

Here's my table definition. I'm using SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODSYNTHESIS_NN]
(
    [Project_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Project_name] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Date_results] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [P_injecte] [real] NULL,
    [P_soutire] [real] NULL,
    [Q_injecte] [real] NULL,
    [Q_soutire] [real] NULL,
    [Zone] [nvarchar](2) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PRODSYNTHESIS] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Project_id] ASC,
                               [Project_name] ASC,
                               [Date_results] ASC)
)
```

And the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_PRODSYNTHESIS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PRODSYNTHESIS_NN'. The duplicate key value is (21, BLAH, Jun  1 2020  8:00AM). (2627) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")

Comment: There is a PR for the official library https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14553